# When does a Eigendecomposition result in a Q with det(Q)=1?

Tags: linear-algebra

With Eigendecomposition I can decompose a symmetric real matrix $A$ into  $Q\Lambda Q^T$, where $Q$ is orthogonal. If $det(Q)=1$, $Q$ is a rotation matrix and if $det(Q)=-1$, $Q$ is a rotation matrix with reflection.

Is there a way to know beforehand if $det(Q)=1$ or $-1$?

Answer (score 4):

You can always arrange that $\det Q = 1$. If $q_1, \ldots, q_n$ is your eigenbasis (the columns of $Q$), note that 
$\det(q_1, \ldots, q_n) = -\det(q_2,q_1,\ldots, q_n)$ and $(q_2,q_1, \ldots, q_n)$ is also an orthonormal eigenbasis.

Comment: But what is the difference between a special orthogonal matrix and a non-special orthogonal matrix, I can always turn $det(Q)$ into +1. See [Introduction at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)

Comment: $\det Q > 0$ for a eigenbasis $Q$ says, that $(e_1, \ldots, e_n)$ (the standard basis) and $(q_1, \ldots, q_n)$ have the same orientation.